# Salto de líneas respuesta ajax en tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

De esta respuesta ajax me devuelve 17 nombres lo cual quiero que me ponga 5 nombres por fila es decir:
NOMBRE 1  NOMBRE2 NOMBRE3 NOMBRE 4 NOMBRE 5
NOMBRE 6  NOMBRE7...

Hago lo siguiente:

```js
var htmlInforme = '<thead> <tr>' 
htmlInforme += '<th style=" font-size: .9em;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #dddddd;padding: 8px;">Fecha</th>'        
var nom


$.ajax({
    url: '/prueba/nombrespy?&t=Nombres,
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(response){ 
        nombres = JSON.parse(response)
          for(var d=0; d<nombres.length; d++){
              nom = nombres[d].nombre
              console.log(nom)
                  htmlInforme += '<th style=" font-size: 0.9em;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #dddddd;">' + nom + '</th>'     
          }    
        }
    });
htmlInforme +='</tr></thead>'
```

Con esto me muestra los 17 nombres en una fila solamente, ajustándose a la pantalla.

Comment: Sin un [example] va a ser imposible ayudarte. No vemos lo que tu ves, y lo que describes no tiene sentido porque desconocemos totalmente tu contexto. Tan solo podemos jugar a las adivinanzas en los comentarios hasta sacarte la información que necesitamos para ayudarte, lo cual cansa y muchos dejaran de ayudarte por esto. Repasa [ask] y [example] y corrige tu pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando iteras debes preguntar si el index es divisible por 5, esto los haces con el operador resto entero

```
if(i%5==0)
```

Seguramente no querras que salte en la primera fila, así que el if quedaria

```
if(i!=0 && i%5==0){
```

Ejemplo:

```js
const nombres = ["nombre1","nombre2","nombre3","nombre4","nombre5","nombre6","nombre7","nombre8","nombre9","nombre10","nombre11","nombre12","nombre13","nombre14","nombre15","nombre16","nombre17"];

const TABLA= document.getElementById("tabla");
function llenartabla(){
  nombres.forEach( (item,i)=>{
    if(i!=0 && i%5==0){
      agregarFila("");
    }
    agregarFila(item);
  });
}

function agregarFila(dato){
     let tr =  document.createElement("tr");
     let td = document.createElement("td");
     td.innerHTML=dato;
     tr.appendChild(td);
     TABLA.appendChild(tr);
}

llenartabla();
```

```css
td{
 height:20px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tbody id="tabla">
</tbody>
<table>
```